# Collision doesn't work. Upon collision, it is supposed to end the game. (instead both objects pass straight through each other)

Tags: python, pygame

I'm working on a space shooter game where you have to dodge asteroids and shoot them. Right now, I'm working on collision for the asteroids. I'm just testing one asteroid for now, but the asteroid passes straight through the ship and doesn't end the game like I want it to.

Here's the code:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

#initalizing all the clunky variables
size = (900,700)
BLACK = (0, 0, 30)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
YELLOW = (0, 255, 0)
x_pos = 450
y_pos = 600
global x_pos
global y_pos
direct = 0
w, h = 100, 100
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
klok = pygame.time.Clock()

#main ship image and its rotations
ship = pygame.image.load('u-sniper.png')
shipL = pygame.transform.rotate(ship, 270)
shipR = pygame.transform.rotate(ship, 90)
shipD = pygame.transform.rotate(ship, 180)
#init hitbox
hitbox = ship.get_rect()
hitbox.center = w//2,h//2

#funct for drawing ship
def drawShip():
    if direct == 0:
        screen.blit(ship, [x_pos,y_pos])
    if direct == 1:
        screen.blit(shipR, [x_pos,y_pos])
    if direct == 2:
        screen.blit(shipD, [x_pos,y_pos])
    if direct == 3:
        screen.blit(shipL, [x_pos,y_pos])

        
        

#asteroid obstacles (these are meant to collide with the ship)
class asteroid:
    def __init__(self,x,y,spawn):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.spawn = spawn

    def drawA(self):
        if self.spawn == 1:
            pygame.draw.circle(screen, RED, (self.x,self.y), 30)

    def moveA(self):
        self.y += 8
        if self.y > 650:
            self.spawn = 0

            
        
    
        
    

        


done = False
roid = asteroid(450,0,1)
#asteroid hitbox init
rect_asteroid = (roid.x, roid.y, 30, 30)


#here is where its going wrong, collision dosent register
def checkForCollisions():
    
    collide = pygame.Rect.colliderect(hitbox,rect_asteroid)
    if collide == True:
        done = True
#loop
while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True
    screen.fill(BLACK)
    drawShip()
    roid.drawA()
    roid.moveA()
    #calling fuction, but it dosent work
    checkForCollisions()
    #if branch that moves the ship
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
            y_pos -= 5
            direct = 0
        if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
            y_pos += 5
            direct = 2
        if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            x_pos += 5
            direct = 3
        if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
            x_pos -= 5
            direct = 1
    
#collision between screen boundaries
    if x_pos > 850:
        x_pos -= 6
    if x_pos < -50:
        x_pos += 6
    if y_pos > 650:
        y_pos -= 6
    if y_pos < 0:
        y_pos += 6

    pygame.display.flip()
    klok.tick(60)
pygame.quit()
```

I tried multiple colliderect functions, but it just results in one thing: the ship and the asteroid pass straight through each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `pygame.Rect` objects do not magically update their position when you change the coordinates used to draw the object. You need to update the location stored in the `pygame.Rect` objects before collision detection. Or just create the objects in `checkForCollisions`:

```py
def checkForCollisions():
    hitbox.topleft = (x_pos, y_pos)
    rect_asteroid = (roid.x, roid.y, 30, 30)
    collide = hitbox.colliderect(rect_asteroid)
    return collide
```